# Best pratices to return from await

Tags: node.js, async-await

This is my signup route :

```
hashed = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, bcryptRounds).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).send();
    return (null);
});
if (hashed === null) {
  return;
}
result = await database.collection("profiles").insertOne({ "username": req.body.username, "password": hashed }).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).send();
    return (null);
});
if (result === null) {
  return;
}
cookie = await SetAuthentification(result.ops[0]._id).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send();
    return (null);
});
if (cookie === null) {
  return;
}
SetAuthentificationCookie(cookie, res);
res.status(200).send();
```

I need to return (null) after every catch and check it to make sure that it didn't fail, but this takes a lot of place and my code is becoming less clear compare to what I had before (but didn't worked in case of error)

```
hashed = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, bcryptRounds).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).send();
});        
result = await database.collection("profiles").insertOne({ "username": req.body.username, "password": hashed }).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).send();
});
cookie = await SetAuthentification(result.ops[0]._id).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send();
});
SetAuthentificationCookie(cookie, res);
res.status(200).send();
```

Any idea on how to improve that part to make it clearer ?

Comment: use a trycatch statement. I notice you are attaching `catch` to collect the error but you can just separate it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just wrap everything into `try...catch`?:

```js
try {
  const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, bcryptRounds);
  const result = await database.collection("profiles").insertOne({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: hashed,
  });
  const cookie = await SetAuthentification(result.ops[0]._id);
  SetAuthentificationCookie(cookie, res);
  res.status(200).send();
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).send();
}
```

If any of the promises reject, the code execution jumps to `catch` block.